# Появление одного из нескольких изображений в зависимости от выпавшего числа

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть JS скрипт, который получает рандомное число и в зависимости от выпавшего числа выводит картинку в блок.

HTML код:

```
<div id="block">
    <a href="#"><img id="pic1" src="pic1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="pic2" src="pic2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="pic3" src="pic3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

JS код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = Math.random();
    i = 3 * i;
    i = Math.floor(i);

    console.log(i);

        if (i==1) {
            document.getElementById("pic1").style.display = 'block';
        }
        else if(i==2){
            document.getElementById("pic2").style.display = 'block';
        }
        else if(i==3){
            document.getElementById("pic3").style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("pic3").style.display = 'block';            
}

</script>
```

CSS код:

```
#pic1{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
display: none;
```

}

```
#pic2{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
display: none;
```

}

```
#pic3{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
display: none;
```

}

При запуске кода, в консоли браузера выводится ошибка - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.

В чем заключается и как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка только в том что скрипт загрузился раньше чем рендер DOM элементов.
Закиньте скрипт в конец документа

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код работает, ошибок нет:

```js
var i = Math.random();
    i = 3 * i;
    i = Math.floor(i);

    console.log(i);

        if (i==1) {
            document.getElementById("pic1").style.display = 'block';
        }
        else if(i==2){
            document.getElementById("pic2").style.display = 'block';
        }
        else if(i==3){
            document.getElementById("pic3").style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("pic3").style.display = 'block';            
}
```

```css
#pic1, #pic2, #pic3{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
    <a href="#"><img id="pic1" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2362009/242fe18c-29cc-490f-8afe-b74cfbe729eb/s1200" alt="Картинка 1"></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="pic2" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/49816/3bf76474-806b-4ccd-94d0-f5506bad867c/s1200" alt="Картинка 2"></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="pic3" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2846431/c42332fc-e861-4564-bd12-90b00524531a/s1200" alt="Картинка 3"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Странно, у меня браузер выдаёт ошибку...

Comment: Что за браузер?

Comment: Opera, но Ваш совет переместить скрипт в конец документа уже помог.